# know the Datatype in Swift

Tags: swift, types

[image: Task]i am new to swift i just started with  the basics. In one of the Blog i saw a simple task which goes like this read a line from the stdin and check whether it is a integer,float,String.

I tried with the following code

```
let input = readLine()
var result = test(input)
print (result)
func test (obj:Any) -> String {

    if obj is Int { return "This input is of type Intger." }
    else if obj is String { return "This input is of type String." }
    else { return "This input is something else. " }
}
```

when the input of 3245 is given it stores in the string format. and  returns output as string.
how to overcome it..?

Answer (score 1):

The `readLine` function returns a value of type `String?`. So your `input` variable can only be a `String`. It will never be `Int` or anything else.

If you want to see if the entered value is a valid number, you can try to convert the string to an `Int`.

```
if let input = readLine() {
    if let num = Int(input) {
        // the user entered a valid integer
    } else {
        // the user entered something other than an integer
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried both the solutions its works one one case ,not for all the cases

Comment: What cases do you mean? Be specific.

Comment: when i try with the line  if let num = Int(input) it shows me warning overloads for the Int64 exists with parameters list Int,Float etc.

Comment: See my update. The problem may have been due to the optional String.

Comment: i have tried the updated even i get the failed results

Comment: As I said, you need to be specific. What do you mean by "failed results"? If you type `345` into my code, you should get to the code where "the user entered a valid integer".

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `readline()` always returns a `String?`. It's up to you to parse that into whatever format you use it.

This is how I would do this:

```
let line = readLine()

switch line {
    case let s? where Int(s) != nil:
        print("This input is of type Intger.")

    case let s? where Float(s) != nil:
        print("This input is of type Float.")

    case let s? where s.hasPrefix("\"") && s.hasSuffix("\""):
        print("This input is of type String.")

    default: print("This input is something else. ")
}
```

It exploits the ability of `Int` and `Float`'s initializers to test the validity of a `String`, which almost entirely defeats the purpose of this exercise. But hey, it works, right?

Comment: What is the purpose of `s.hasPrefix("")` ? That should be true for all strings. Or did you mean `s.hasPrefix("\"")` ?

Comment: @MartinR I sure did :)

Answer (score -2):

You can find of the type of object as

```
   if let intt = obj as? Int {
      // obj is a String. Do something with intt
   }
   else if let str = obj as? String {
      // obj is a String. Do something with str
   }
   else {
    //obj is something else
```

}

Comment: You need to read the question and the other answers to see why your answer has nothing to do with the question being asked.